# Getting data from selected row in DataGridView, C# WinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core, datagridview

How to read whole row and save it to variable? I know what type is stored there (custom Employee type).

I have tried doing it kind of manually.

```cs
private async void AddEmployee()
        {
            var context = new NorthwindContext();
            int selectedRowCount = EmpMgmtDataGridView.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
            if (selectedRowCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
                {
                    var employeeToAdd = new Employees();
                    employeeToAdd.FirstName = EmpMgmtDataGridView[1, i].ToString();
                    employeeToAdd.LastName = EmpMgmtDataGridView[2, i].ToString();
                    await context.AddAsync(employeeToAdd);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
        }
```

But it ends with

```
SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

at SaveChanges.
I'm trying to send it into database, but i know how to do it, i just can't get it from DataGridView.

Edit

Made an upgrade but it ends with identical error.

```cs
private async void AddEmployee()
        {
            var context = new NorthwindContext();
            int selectedRowCount = EmpMgmtDataGridView.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
            var rows = EmpMgmtDataGridView.SelectedRows;
            if (selectedRowCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
                {
                    var employeeToAdd = new Employees();
                    employeeToAdd.LastName = rows[i].Cells[1].ToString();
                    employeeToAdd.FirstName = rows[i].Cells[2].ToString();
                    await context.AddAsync(employeeToAdd);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are actually getting the **Value** of the cell rather than the cell object itself:

```
employeeToAdd.LastName = rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
employeeToAdd.FirstName = rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you for help. I'm pretty sure i will have trouble getting out dates (since they are not string) but i will try to search for solution first.

Comment: No problem. Probably the length of `Cells[x].ToString()` was too long for the database to handle.
You would be able to get dates similarly by simply parsing Cells[x].Value to DateTime.